# How to add transaction (eCommerce) in Google analytics using Node JS?

Tags: node.js, google-analytics

Currently, I am using googleapis npm modules for add transaction below is the link for the same.

[Googleapis Nodemodules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis)

I am not getting any way to add transaction for e-commerce tracking using Node JS.

I got a way to do this functionality using Javascript below is the link for the same.

[Click here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce)

It would be great if you will provide some sample code or Link for the same.

Answer (score 4):

You have 3 ways to send data to Google Analytics:

- **Client-side tracking**: such as web browser ([gtag.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/), [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/), [AMP HTML](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/)), or mobile ([iOS](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/firebase/ios/) or [Android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/firebase/android/))
- **Data Import**: these are bulk imports you can do either [manually](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191589?hl=en) or through the [management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/uploadData) (more specifically the [v3 analytics uploadData endpoint](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/src/apis/analytics/v3.ts#L9197))
- **Server-side tracking**: this is done via the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference) which the [official Google API client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) you mentioned **doesn't provide an interface for**. Instead you want to use [a package such as this one](https://github.com/peaksandpies/universal-analytics) (there may be others, just search on Github)

The code for sending a transaction using the aforementioned package would look as follows:

```
visitor
  .transaction({ti: "trans-12345", tr: 500, ts: 50, tt: 100, ta: "Partner 13"})
  .item({ip: 300, iq: 1, ic: "item-54321", in: "Item 54321", iv: "Blue"})
  .item({ip: 200, iq: 2, ic: "item-41325", in: "Item 41325", iv: "XXL"})
  .send()
```